# Error parsing data from php into android list view

Tags: php, android, json

I have  my php web serivce that retrieves a list of topics from my forum and I used JSON to pare is into listview in my Android app.

Unfortunately when running the app and when I go the the page where I should see that list I get black blank screen and in my logcat I got this error

```
03-17 15:00:04.189: E/JSON Parser(379): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

here is my JSONparser class

```
package com.example.androidhive.library;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }       

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

     public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

        }


}
```

I have two  public JSONobject the first one I for user reg. an login and the second one is for the topic list view..where I assume the error comes from

this is the php

```
        <?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . 'DB_Connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
if(isset($_GET['parent']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['parent']);}
$result = mysql_query("select t.id, t.title, u.username as author,  from topics as t  left join user as u where t.parent="'.$id.'" and t.id2=1 group by t.id order by t.timestamp2 desc');
") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["topics"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $topic = array();
    $topic["tid"] = $row["t.id"];
    $topic["name"] = $row["t.title"];
    $topic["author"] = $row["u.username"];


    // push single product into final response array

    array_push($response["topics"], $topic);
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No topics found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

this is the string I got from server

```
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <head>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <title>Object not found!</title>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):     body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):     a:link { color: #0000CC; }
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):     p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):     span {font-size: smaller;}
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): /*]]>*/--></style>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): </head>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <body>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <h1>Object not found!</h1>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <p>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):     The requested URL was not found on this server.
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):   
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):     If you entered the URL manually please check your
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):     spelling and try again.
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):   
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): </p>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <p>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): If you think this is a server error, please contact
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): </p>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <h2>Error 404</h2>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): <address>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):   <a href="/">10.0.2.2</a><br />
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502):   <span>Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7</span>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): </address>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): </body>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON(502): </html>
03-17 16:04:21.599: E/JSON Parser(502): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

the url and to get data from server and the parameters are

```
private static String url_all_topics = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/list_of_topics.php";

 // JSON Node names
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 private static final String TAG_TOPICS = "topics";
 private static final String TAG_TOPICSID = "t.id";
private static final String TAG_TOPICTITLE = "t.title";
private static final String TAG_TOPICAUTHOR = "u.username";
```

I have found this in and online tutorial but I edit it to suit my requirements

I hope you be patient with me as I'm not so good and I'm new in this stuff and wanna learn

Comment: Can you show the string that you are trying to parse that is causing the error?

Comment: Print responce to log. It will easier find problem cause when we see that "bad" json string

Comment: I'd say the PHP response starts with "<?xml". The reason is probably that the content type for the PHP script is not set/wrongly set, such that the server adjusts the header of what it thinks is going to be XML. The content type for the response must be set such that it can be detected as JSON.

Comment: @mikeshorts as I said I'm trying to pares list of topics from my forum  I'm sorry but  don't understand how can I bring the sting here!!

Comment: @AlekseyMaximus how can I do it

Comment: @captinmemo : plz post whole String which u are getting form server in response

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK for the time being I only get this error in my logcat and I got blank screen in my Android....should the string be found somewhere else plz do guide me

Comment: @captinmemo : put `Log.e("JSON", sb.toString());` before `json = sb.toString();` and add String which u are getting in logcat with question

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I really appreciate your help I have edited the question you may check it

Comment: @captinmemo : as in log *The requested URL was not found on this server.* means u are using work url to get data from server. plz share url and also parameter which u are using for getting data from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server returned [HTTP 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) error code, which means that **your script was not run at all**.

Verify that you are accessing correct URL in your app.

Comment: Ops I found that I'm directing it to incomplete address.. but I correct it now then run it after the correction I have edited the question with the current php code which gives me this error            03-17 16:32:05.169: E/JSON(564): <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ''.$id.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\include\list_of_topics.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
03-17 16:32:05.289: E/JSON Parser(564): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject